# Complex SQL query with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structures, I'm working on someone else's code unfortunately & still getting to grips with it all. The tables below are orders (or purchases) made by customers & the 'products' table (I've omitted some columns for extra clarity as they are not important to explain the problem). I've added the existing query that I need to edit:

```
#products table * - primary key
shop_products(product_id, organisation_id, product_name, product_type_id, Guid*, active, quantity, multi_buy...)

#purchases table * - primary key
shop_purchases(purchase_id*, user_id, price, Guid, refunded)

SELECT * FROM `shop_products` `t`
  WHERE `t`.`organisation_id`=25679
    AND (IF( availability=3,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM shop_product_years
         WHERE shop_product_years.Guid = t.Guid
           AND shop_product_years.year_id = 10) > 0, (availability=1
                                                      OR availability = 2))                                                          
    AND (multi_buy = 1
        OR (multi_buy = 0
            AND
              ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM shop_purchases
               WHERE shop_purchases.user_id = 5702079181
                 AND shop_purchases.GUID = t.Guid
                        AND shop_purchases.refunded = 1) = 0
            AND
              ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM shop_purchases_queue
               WHERE shop_purchases_queue.user_id = 5702079181
                 AND shop_purchases_queue.GUID = t.Guid) = 0)       
              )
   AND active=1
   AND product_type_id=11)
```

I basically want to modify the query so if the product is a MULTI BUY (e.g multi_buy=1) and the QUANTITY is greater than 0, Count the number of existing purchases for that item (using the Guid). If the number of purchases for that item for that user is LESS than the QUANTITY then we can grab the product and display this row in the rows returned, OTHERWISE as the quantity is NOT LESS than count then we cannot display this product in the rows.

The idea is a product can only be ordered a set number of times (but only if the quantity is GREATER than 0) Once the number of times and item is ordered for that user has been reached the set quantity the user is no longer able to order this.

I hope that makes sense - please let me know if you wish me to clarify it further.

Comment: Can you please add a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: good idea - i'll do that shortly :)

Comment: Just my luck... SQLFiddle's website is down Grrrr... built on Coldfusion apparently